# Handle rotation of password in spring cloud stream consumers when connected to MSK kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, aws-secrets-manager, aws-msk

I have a Kafka consumer written using Spring Cloud Stream which connects to Kafka deployed on Amazon MSK cluster with secret manager for periodic password rotation.

Problem:

Do I need to re-instantiate the application on every password rotation?
If yes, is there a standard way to do it using Spring Cloud Stream?

Current solution:
We have implemented a health check based on the Spring actuator. In case of binder connection failure we restart the ECS.

The current solution is very un-stable as we are still getting SASLAuthentication exception which is not captured by the health check and there is no re-instantiation of the application

Please, suggest me a way out.

Comment: @gary-russell Could you please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You can reconfigure the consumer and producer factory (with the new credentials).

On the producer side, call `reset()` on the factory to close the existing producer(s) and reconnect on demand.

On the consumer side, you can `stop()` and `start()` the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` to close and reconnect the consumers.